# UFW and firewall

Tags: security, firewall, iptables, ufw

So I recently installed ubuntu and I have been working with it no problem.While browsing through the security guides (specifically: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity) I noticed this: "enable the firewall (sudo ufw enable) without further tweaks;" After some further reading I found out that ubuntu comes with the kernel firewall and ufw is just an easier iptables manipulator so why do I need to enable it without any tweaks?

Or am I completely wrong and there is another reason its required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert, just a user with some experience.  I think you misread https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall

iptables is a set of rules in a file which are the basis for what the firewall can/should do.  The UFW program is a command line interface for interfacing with the firewall (enable, disable, status) and modifying the iptables rules without directly editing the iptables.  GUFW is a HUI based program to do the same thing.  When you run "sudo ufw enable" you are not turning ufw on, you are turning on the firewall.

Comment: Yea thats what I thought at first but it seemed wierd to be the firewall disabled as they are usually of of the first lines of defence

Answer (score 0):

It says just enable firewall with default configuration. If you do not have any idea what is or not, do not tweak it. By the way ufw is the kernel firewall you mentioned.

Comment: Meaning ubuntu has firewall completely off by default? who thought of that!

Comment: When you install ubuntu, the firewall is disabled by default. You can check it by typing "service ufw status".

Comment: Uhh isnt that a huge security hole if its off by default?

Comment: Firewall does packet filtering, so it slows the network traffic a little bit. In case you already behind a firewall, generally it is disabled.

Comment: It is not a security hole as I said previous comment.